# Neo4j do multiple task on an identifier

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in a Cypher query i have multiple `MATCH` i will pass an id with `WITH` to second part of my query
 s

```
MATCH user-[:friend*2..3]-other
WHERE NOT user-[:friend]-other
WITH user,other
MATCH user-[:played_in]->uni<-[:played_in]-other
CREATE UNIQUE user-[k:may_know]-other
SET k.w = (k.w) + 1

MATCH user-[:friend*2..3]-other
WHERE NOT user-[:friend]-other
WITH user,other
MATCH user-[:lives_in]->c<-[:lives_in]-other
CREATE UNIQUE user-[k:may_know]-other
SET k.w = (k.w) + 1
```

in second part i should examine result with another `MATCH` and do some update task for each match

i can repeat first part for each second part but is there any way to avoid changing result from first part and reuse it several times?
something like copying result in another identifire or something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you provide a more precise example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match on multiple relationships, e.g. played_in, lives_in, you can do this I think :

```
MATCH user-[:friend*2..3]-other
WHERE NOT user-[:friend]-other
WITH user,other
MATCH p=user-[r1:played_in|:lives_in]->(l)<-[r2:played_in|:lives_in]-other
WHERE l:University or l:City
WHERE type(r1) = type(r2)
FOREACH (path IN p | 
    MERGE startNode(path)-[k:may_know]-endNode(path)
    ON CREATE SET k.w = 1
    ON MATCH SET k.w = (k.w) +1
    )
```